# Generated tests when scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After making a new rails 3.2.3 application, I generated a new scaffold to play around with some code.  I was running some rake tasks later on and accidentally entered 'rake' without any arguments.  To my surprise, it ran 7 tests and 10 assertions with 0 failures...  Why?  I didn't add any tests to the application.

Were these tests generated with the scaffold?  It appears that the tests are located in the /test directory.  I want to use rspec, not test::unit or anything like that.  If this is something other than rspec, is it safe to just deleted the /test directory or is there more underlying work to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The tests are generated along with the scaffolding. They don't do much more than `assert` that the scaffold controller is routing correctly, but you can safely remove them. It's probably best to remove the test files themselves rather than the entire `test` directory (just in case you end up having any use for `Test::Unit` down the line), but you can find all of the generated tests in the following subdirectories:

```
test/functional
test/unit/
test/unit/helpers
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely delete the test directory. If you want to tell Rails to use rspec and not generate test::unit anymore, add this to your config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.view_specs      false
  g.helper_specs    false
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.test_framework  :rspec
  g.helpers         false
end
```

The above would also not generate view specs, helper specs, or helpers.

Comment: Or just use `gem 'rspec-rails'` which will handle usage RSpec in generators.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's safe to delete that directory if you want to use RSpec instead. When you generate a new application, pass the `-T` flag to the `new` command to not have Rails automatically setup tests for you.

```
rails new app_name -T
```